# jquery and javascript code, subsequent executions give unexpected outputs, the first being the desired output

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, animation, jquery-animate

i have a grid of images, and i desire to enlarge a div id=box, from the clicked on image to the entire grid space with the specified animation, and close the same way. The first round takes place perfectly, but the subsequent rounds are executed in unexpected funny manners.
javascript is just to position the div over the clicked image. the animation, appearing and disappearing is done using jquery. im not very good with jquery but couldnt resist the animation options. please suggest a suitable alternate or a solution to this unusual behaviour.
thansks.

```
function box(id)
{var tpos = document.getElementById(id).offsetTop;
var lpos = document.getElementById(id).offsetLeft;
document.getElementById('box').style.top= tpos;
document.getElementById('box').style.left= lpos;
setTimeout(function(){jqueryfunc();},800);}

jqueryfunc = function(){
var box= $('#box');
$('#close').show();
box.show();
var ileft=box.css("left");
var itop=box.css("top");
box.animate({width:'793px',left:'06px'},1000);
box.animate({height:'446px',top:'31px'},1000);

jqueryclose = $(function(){
$('#close').click(function(){
$('#close').hide();
box.animate({width: '157px', left: ileft},1000);
box.animate({height: '110px', top: itop},1000);
box.fadeOut('slow');
}); }); };
```

Comment: can you please give us url to your website?

Comment: provide a demo in jsfiddle.net...not link to a site. A link to a site may be broken in the future and serve little value for others at a later date

Comment: @charlietfl wow man so caring bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the DOM ready function to a variable, and expecting variables to work in different scopes etc. Try something more like this:

```
function box(id) {
    var elem = $('#'+id),
        offset = elem.offset(),
        box = $('#box');

    elem.css({top: offset.top, left: offset.left});
    setTimeout(jqueryfunc, 800);
}

function jqueryfunc() {
    $('#close').show();
    $('#box').show().animate({width: 793, left: 6}, 1000)
             .animate({height: 446, top: 31}, 1000);

}

$(function() {
    $('#close').click(function() {
        var box = $('#box'),
            ileft = box.css("left"),
            itop = box.css("top");
        $('#close').hide();
            box.animate({width: 157, left: ileft}, 1000)
               .animate({height: 110, top: itop}, 1000)
               .fadeOut('slow');
    });
});​
```

It does'nt look like you are calling the box() function anywhere either ?

Comment: i need the box to go back to the same position it expanded from, this way it would just go to the smaller size at the same position..

Comment: I have a feeling he is calling the box function from a click event or similar that would have bound n+1 identical events to the #close in his code. This would fix that problem I think as well... probably need more code from op

Comment: the box function is called, once you click on the image, with the id of the image div, giving the same size and position to the appearing div, and then it expands from it..

Comment: the #close appears above the enlarged image to close and get back to the normal div, the positioning is css, and the display default is none.

Comment: i need a way to get the innitial offset positions back to the final function such that the animations end where they started. i had to combine functions to do so, and im guessing thats where the problem lies.

Comment: Probably is, as you are attaching event handlers and calling DOM ready functions within a function that is called everytime an image is clicked, so it just keeps adding on. This is as far as I can get from the code in the question, as it's not complete, and it's hard to tell exactly what it is you're trying to do. Try setting this is up in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we have something more to go on, as it's almost impossible to figure out a solution other than fixing the obvious errors without some more code.

Comment: there is no result though, ive not used this before.